# In Python, how should one extract the second-last directory name in a path?

Tags: python, string, path, split, slash

I have a string like the following:

```
/cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/sw/ASG/AnalysisTop/2.0.24/RootCore
```

How should I extract the "2.0.24" from this string? I'm not sure how to split the string using the slashes (in order to extract the second last element of the resultant list) and I'm not sure if this would be a good approach. What I have right now is the following:

```
"/cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/sw/ASG/AnalysisTop/2.0.24/RootCore".split("/RootCore")[0].split("AnalysisTop/")[1]
```

Comment: The number is changeable or not?

Comment: The number could change, yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
'/cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/sw/ASG/AnalysisTop/2.0.24/RootCore'.split('/')[-2]
```

Comment: This is not portable across all filesystems. E.g., Windows uses a `\` to separate directories

Answer (score 12):

You can also do:

```
import os
x = "/cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/sw/ASG/AnalysisTop/2.0.24/RootCore"
os.path.split(os.path.split(x)[0])[1]
```

results in

```
'2.0.24'
```

Comment: I don't understand why you received a down vote. It is an interesting approach.

Answer (score 5):

cross platform solution:

```
import os
'your/path'.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just split according to the `/` symbol then print the second index from the last.

```
>>> x = "/cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/sw/ASG/AnalysisTop/2.0.24/RootCore"
>>> y = x.split('/')
>>> y[-2]
'2.0.24'
```

Comment: So what if the string has more than 2 strings at the end? split('/')[-2] will fail

Answer (score -1):

```
path = "/cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/sw/ASG/AnalysisTop/2.0.24/RootCore"
path_dirs = path.split("/")

>>>> path_dirs
>>>> ['', 'cvmfs', 'atlas.cern.ch', 'repo', 'sw', 'ASG', 'AnalysisTop', '2.0.24', 'RootCore']

>>>> print path_dirs[-2]
>>>> '2.0.24'
```

Comment: Sorry fixed it ! @Trengot

Answer (score -2):

```
import re

str1 = "/cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/sw/ASG/AnalysisTop/2.0.24/RootCore"
t = re.findall("[0-9][.]*",str1)
print ("".join(t))
```

You can use `regex`-`findall` method. `t` returns a list, so using `join()`.

Output;

```
>>> 
2.0.24
>>> 

# print (t)
>>> 
['2.', '0.', '2', '4']
>>>
```

Comment: This is not the best solution. It might work in this case but not generic. what if you have /aaa/bbb/11/a/13/ ...

Comment: So what if the string has more than 2 strings at the end? `split('/')[-2]` will fail. Dots are not change probably, so it's the best one I guess.